# Podio > Azure DB > MS PowerBI - Parsing JSON "Fields" column

Tags: json, parsing, powerbi, podio

*(Non-DB guy trying to do DB stuff)*

**Scenario:** Incoming Azure DB data source to MSFT PowerBI with data replicated from a Podio app (if you have an easier way please let me know). In PowerBI - I'm having trouble parsing the JSON column correctly. Here's where I'm at:

- Parsed the column in Power Query Editor, I get a List value
  [Step 1: Parse JSON Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3M8g.png)
- Expanded the parsed column to new rows, it returns Records
  [Step 2: Expand to New Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loFGa.png)
- Expanded column to show label and values, returns lists
  [Step 3: Expand Column (label/values elements)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oSN3.png)
- Expanded Fields.values (expecting them all to show up, get records)
  [Step 4: Expand Fields.values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NcLm.png)
- Extract Values (Get some, not all)
  [Step 5: Extract Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iimfv.png)
- Resulting Column
  [Step 5: The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m52R7.png)

This is where I haven't been able to pass. I've reviewed some similar posts and attempted paths (New Queries / adding the records as new tables) but have not been successful. Please let me know if anyone can help :)

**M-Code**

```
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
    let
    Source = Sql.Database("[server]", "[database]"),
    dbo_Items = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Items"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(dbo_Items,{"FileIds", "Comments"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"AppItemIdFormatted", "LastEventOn", "Fields", "Title", "InitialRevision_CreatedOn", "InitialRevision_UserName", "CurrentRevision_CreatedOn", "CreatedDate", "Link", "CreatedVia_Name", "CreatedBy_Name", "CurrentRevision_UserName"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

**JSON Sample**

```
[{"type":"text","field_id":78689714,"label":"Subject","values":[{"value":"Driver rear Quartz light out"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"plain","size":"small"},"mapping":null,"label":"Subject"},"external_id":"subject"},{"type":"contact","field_id":78689715,"label":"Issue Contact","values":[{"value":{"user_id":null,"space_id":1365655,"type":"space","image":null,"profile_id":164532537,"org_id":null,"phone":["7035902402"],"link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/irons/contacts/164532537","mail":["sriley@pwcgov.org"],"external_id":null,"last_seen_on":null,"name":"shawn Riley"}}],"config":{"settings":{"type":"space_contacts","valid_types":["space"]},"mapping":null,"label":"Issue Contact"},"external_id":"issue-contact"},{"type":"category","field_id":78690387,"label":"Category","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Apparatus","id":2,"color":"DCEBD8"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"--- SELECT ---","id":1,"color":"DCEBD8"},{"status":"active","text":"Apparatus","id":2,"color":"DCEBD8"},{"status":"active","text":"Communications","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Equipment","id":4,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"House & Grounds","id":5,"color":"DDDDDD"},{"status":"active","text":"Information Technology","id":6,"color":"D2E4EB"},{"status":"active","text":"SCBA","id":7,"color":"E1D8ED"}],"display":"dropdown"},"mapping":null,"label":"Category"},"external_id":"category-2"},{"type":"category","field_id":78689716,"label":"Issue Status","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Closed","id":3,"color":"D1F3EC"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"Open","id":1,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"In-Progress","id":2,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Closed","id":3,"color":"D1F3EC"}],"display":"inline"},"mapping":null,"label":"Issue Status"},"external_id":"category"},{"type":"category","field_id":78689717,"label":"Priority","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Low","id":4,"color":"D2E4EB"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"Low","id":4,"color":"D2E4EB"},{"status":"active","text":"Normal","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Urgent","id":2,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"Emergency (Unit OOS)","id":1,"color":"F7D1D0"}],"display":"inline"},"mapping":null,"label":"Priority"},"external_id":"priority"},{"type":"app","field_id":78689718,"label":"Location","values":[{"value":{"files":[],"sharefile_vault_url":null,"space":{"sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"Administration","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration","url_label":"administration","item_accounting_info":null,"org_id":139576,"type":"regular","space_id":1305303},"app_item_id":2,"app":{"status":"active","sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"DCVFD Stations","space_id":1305303,"default_view_id":null,"url_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/new","icon_id":62,"link_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/new","app_id":4915754,"current_revision":6,"is_default":false,"item_name":"Station","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations","url_label":"dcvfd-stations","config":{"item_name":"Station","icon_id":62,"type":"standard","name":"DCVFD Stations","icon":"62.png"},"item_accounting_info":null,"icon":"62.png"},"title":"Station 13","initial_revision":{"item_revision_id":117004666,"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":1,"display":false,"name":"Podio","id":1},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2013-07-22 02:59:22","user":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"type":"creation","revision":0},"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":1,"display":false,"name":"Podio","id":1},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2013-07-22 02:59:22","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/2","item_id":64885951,"sharefile_vault_folder_id":null,"revision":1}}],"config":{"settings":{"referenced_apps":[{"view_id":null,"app_id":4915754}],"multiple":true,"referenceable_types":[4915754]},"mapping":null,"label":"Location"},"external_id":"location"},{"type":"app","field_id":78689719,"label":"Unit","values":[{"value":{"files":[],"sharefile_vault_url":null,"space":{"sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"Apparatus & Maintenance","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus","url_label":"apparatus","item_accounting_info":null,"org_id":139576,"type":"regular","space_id":1739902},"app_item_id":21,"app":{"status":"active","sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"Apparatus","space_id":1739902,"default_view_id":null,"url_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus/items/new","icon_id":217,"link_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus/items/new","app_id":8314603,"current_revision":15,"is_default":false,"item_name":"Unit","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus","url_label":"apparatus","config":{"item_name":"Unit","icon_id":217,"type":"standard","name":"Apparatus","icon":"217.png"},"item_accounting_info":null,"icon":"217.png"},"title":"TW513 (DC-17)","initial_revision":{"item_revision_id":604291659,"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":1,"display":false,"name":"Podio","id":1},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2015-06-28 22:02:52","user":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"type":"update","revision":4},"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":5552,"display":false,"name":"AppContentBatch","id":5552},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2014-06-03 15:59:48","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus/items/21","item_id":162508718,"sharefile_vault_folder_id":null,"revision":33}}],"config":{"settings":{"referenced_apps":[{"view_id":null,"app_id":8314603}],"multiple":true,"referenceable_types":[8314603]},"mapping":null,"label":"Unit"},"external_id":"unit-if-applicable"},{"type":"text","field_id":78689720,"label":"Details","values":[{"value":"<p>Upon checkout, the driver rear Quartz light is out. Checked plug to ensure it was plugged in. Notice scotch marks on bulb.</p>"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"html","size":"large"},"mapping":null,"label":"Details"},"external_id":"details"},{"type":"text","field_id":78689721,"label":"Resolution","values":[{"value":"<p>Light is fixed</p>"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"html","size":"large"},"mapping":null,"label":"Resolution"},"external_id":"resolution"}]
[{"type":"text","field_id":78689714,"label":"Subject","values":[{"value":"Pedi pads for lifepak 15"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"plain","size":"small"},"mapping":null,"label":"Subject"},"external_id":"subject"},{"type":"contact","field_id":78689715,"label":"Issue Contact","values":[{"value":{"user_id":null,"space_id":1365655,"type":"space","image":null,"profile_id":164530812,"org_id":null,"phone":["703-590-2402"],"link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/irons/contacts/164530812","mail":["Dstewart2@pwcgov.org"],"external_id":null,"last_seen_on":null,"name":"David Stewart"}}],"config":{"settings":{"type":"space_contacts","valid_types":["space"]},"mapping":null,"label":"Issue Contact"},"external_id":"issue-contact"},{"type":"category","field_id":78690387,"label":"Category","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Equipment","id":4,"color":"FFD5C2"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"--- SELECT ---","id":1,"color":"DCEBD8"},{"status":"active","text":"Apparatus","id":2,"color":"DCEBD8"},{"status":"active","text":"Communications","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Equipment","id":4,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"House & Grounds","id":5,"color":"DDDDDD"},{"status":"active","text":"Information Technology","id":6,"color":"D2E4EB"},{"status":"active","text":"SCBA","id":7,"color":"E1D8ED"}],"display":"dropdown"},"mapping":null,"label":"Category"},"external_id":"category-2"},{"type":"category","field_id":78689716,"label":"Issue Status","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Closed","id":3,"color":"D1F3EC"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"Open","id":1,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"In-Progress","id":2,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Closed","id":3,"color":"D1F3EC"}],"display":"inline"},"mapping":null,"label":"Issue Status"},"external_id":"category"},{"type":"category","field_id":78689717,"label":"Priority","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Normal","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"Low","id":4,"color":"D2E4EB"},{"status":"active","text":"Normal","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Urgent","id":2,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"Emergency (Unit OOS)","id":1,"color":"F7D1D0"}],"display":"inline"},"mapping":null,"label":"Priority"},"external_id":"priority"},{"type":"app","field_id":78689718,"label":"Location","values":[{"value":{"files":[],"sharefile_vault_url":null,"space":{"sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"Administration","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration","url_label":"administration","item_accounting_info":null,"org_id":139576,"type":"regular","space_id":1305303},"app_item_id":2,"app":{"status":"active","sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"DCVFD Stations","space_id":1305303,"default_view_id":null,"url_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/new","icon_id":62,"link_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/new","app_id":4915754,"current_revision":6,"is_default":false,"item_name":"Station","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations","url_label":"dcvfd-stations","config":{"item_name":"Station","icon_id":62,"type":"standard","name":"DCVFD Stations","icon":"62.png"},"item_accounting_info":null,"icon":"62.png"},"title":"Station 13","initial_revision":{"item_revision_id":117004666,"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":1,"display":false,"name":"Podio","id":1},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2013-07-22 02:59:22","user":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"type":"creation","revision":0},"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":1,"display":false,"name":"Podio","id":1},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2013-07-22 02:59:22","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/2","item_id":64885951,"sharefile_vault_folder_id":null,"revision":1}}],"config":{"settings":{"referenced_apps":[{"view_id":null,"app_id":4915754}],"multiple":true,"referenceable_types":[4915754]},"mapping":null,"label":"Location"},"external_id":"location"},{"type":"app","field_id":78689719,"label":"Unit","values":[{"value":{"files":[],"sharefile_vault_url":null,"space":{"sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"Apparatus & Maintenance","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus","url_label":"apparatus","item_accounting_info":null,"org_id":139576,"type":"regular","space_id":1739902},"app_item_id":23,"app":{"status":"active","sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"Apparatus","space_id":1739902,"default_view_id":null,"url_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus/items/new","icon_id":217,"link_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus/items/new","app_id":8314603,"current_revision":15,"is_default":false,"item_name":"Unit","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus","url_label":"apparatus","config":{"item_name":"Unit","icon_id":217,"type":"standard","name":"Apparatus","icon":"217.png"},"item_accounting_info":null,"icon":"217.png"},"title":"(DC-19) Old Disopsed of 6/17","initial_revision":{"item_revision_id":298435223,"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":5552,"display":false,"name":"AppContentBatch","id":5552},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2014-06-03 15:59:48","user":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"type":"creation","revision":0},"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":5552,"display":false,"name":"AppContentBatch","id":5552},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2014-06-03 15:59:48","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/apparatus/apps/apparatus/items/23","item_id":162508720,"sharefile_vault_folder_id":null,"revision":13}}],"config":{"settings":{"referenced_apps":[{"view_id":null,"app_id":8314603}],"multiple":true,"referenceable_types":[8314603]},"mapping":null,"label":"Unit"},"external_id":"unit-if-applicable"},{"type":"text","field_id":78689720,"label":"Details","values":[{"value":"<p>There are no indate pedi pads for the lifepak 15</p>"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"html","size":"large"},"mapping":null,"label":"Details"},"external_id":"details"}]
[{"type":"text","field_id":78689714,"label":"Subject","values":[{"value":"Female Bunk Red Alarm Light"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"plain","size":"small"},"mapping":null,"label":"Subject"},"external_id":"subject"},{"type":"contact","field_id":78689715,"label":"Issue Contact","values":[{"value":{"user_id":null,"space_id":1365655,"type":"space","image":null,"profile_id":108228453,"org_id":null,"phone":["571-228-5858"],"link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/irons/contacts/108228453","mail":["yabduljawad@dcvfd.org"],"external_id":null,"last_seen_on":null,"name":"Yumn Abduljawad"}}],"config":{"settings":{"type":"space_contacts","valid_types":["space"]},"mapping":null,"label":"Issue Contact"},"external_id":"issue-contact"},{"type":"category","field_id":78690387,"label":"Category","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"House & Grounds","id":5,"color":"DDDDDD"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"--- SELECT ---","id":1,"color":"DCEBD8"},{"status":"active","text":"Apparatus","id":2,"color":"DCEBD8"},{"status":"active","text":"Communications","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Equipment","id":4,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"House & Grounds","id":5,"color":"DDDDDD"},{"status":"active","text":"Information Technology","id":6,"color":"D2E4EB"},{"status":"active","text":"SCBA","id":7,"color":"E1D8ED"}],"display":"dropdown"},"mapping":null,"label":"Category"},"external_id":"category-2"},{"type":"category","field_id":78689716,"label":"Issue Status","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Closed","id":3,"color":"D1F3EC"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"Open","id":1,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"In-Progress","id":2,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Closed","id":3,"color":"D1F3EC"}],"display":"inline"},"mapping":null,"label":"Issue Status"},"external_id":"category"},{"type":"category","field_id":78689717,"label":"Priority","values":[{"value":{"status":"active","text":"Normal","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"}}],"config":{"settings":{"multiple":false,"options":[{"status":"active","text":"Low","id":4,"color":"D2E4EB"},{"status":"active","text":"Normal","id":3,"color":"F7F0C5"},{"status":"active","text":"Urgent","id":2,"color":"FFD5C2"},{"status":"active","text":"Emergency (Unit OOS)","id":1,"color":"F7D1D0"}],"display":"inline"},"mapping":null,"label":"Priority"},"external_id":"priority"},{"type":"app","field_id":78689718,"label":"Location","values":[{"value":{"files":[],"sharefile_vault_url":null,"space":{"sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"Administration","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration","url_label":"administration","item_accounting_info":null,"org_id":139576,"type":"regular","space_id":1305303},"app_item_id":2,"app":{"status":"active","sharefile_vault_url":null,"name":"DCVFD Stations","space_id":1305303,"default_view_id":null,"url_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/new","icon_id":62,"link_add":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/new","app_id":4915754,"current_revision":6,"is_default":false,"item_name":"Station","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations","url":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations","url_label":"dcvfd-stations","config":{"item_name":"Station","icon_id":62,"type":"standard","name":"DCVFD Stations","icon":"62.png"},"item_accounting_info":null,"icon":"62.png"},"title":"Station 13","initial_revision":{"item_revision_id":117004666,"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":1,"display":false,"name":"Podio","id":1},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2013-07-22 02:59:22","user":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"type":"creation","revision":0},"created_via":{"url":null,"auth_client_id":1,"display":false,"name":"Podio","id":1},"created_by":{"user_id":828696,"name":"RJ Best","url":"https://podio.com/users/828696","type":"user","image":{"hosted_by":"podio","hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio","thumbnail_link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","link":"https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/105283507","file_id":105283507,"external_file_id":null,"link_target":"_blank"},"avatar_type":"file","avatar":105283507,"id":828696,"avatar_id":105283507,"last_seen_on":"2020-01-05 16:51:52"},"created_on":"2013-07-22 02:59:22","link":"https://podio.com/dcvfd/administration/apps/dcvfd-stations/items/2","item_id":64885951,"sharefile_vault_folder_id":null,"revision":1}}],"config":{"settings":{"referenced_apps":[{"view_id":null,"app_id":4915754}],"multiple":true,"referenceable_types":[4915754]},"mapping":null,"label":"Location"},"external_id":"location"},{"type":"text","field_id":78689720,"label":"Details","values":[{"value":"<p>The red alarm light in the middle female bunk room doesn&#39;t come one when we get a call nor does it come on when you change settings on the westnet box.</p>"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"html","size":"large"},"mapping":null,"label":"Details"},"external_id":"details"},{"type":"text","field_id":78689721,"label":"Resolution","values":[{"value":"<p>Repair</p>"}],"config":{"settings":{"format":"html","size":"large"},"mapping":null,"label":"Resolution"},"external_id":"resolution"}]
```

Comment: Apparently, there should be some difference in the JSON schema. Can you share examples of raw JSON in which case you can retrieve the value and which case you cannot. Also can you share the M code in Advanced Editor?

Comment: Added @KosukeSakai.

Comment: Thank you. You should mask personal info in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the shcema of your JSON. When looking at each entry of `$[*].values[*].value`, it is either a String or an Object. Looks like when `$[*].type` is "text", it is a String, whereas when it is another value, such as "contact", "category", or "app", it is an Object.

So, depending on your requirement, you may get rid of Object entries from the output using `Table.SelectRows`, or turn them to some String values that represents the Object using `Table.TransformColumns`.